# if elements of array 1 exists in array 2

Tags: php, arrays

It's a bit like in_array but while in_array checks the presence of one element in an array and returns true and false accordingly, I want to know whether all elements of array1 is part of array2.

Ex:

```
$array1 = array(3, 30);
$array2 = array(5, 30);
$array3 = array(5, 50);

$array = array(50,7,8,456,1,5,567);

function new_in_array($array1,$array) // false
function new_in_array($array2,$array) // false
function new_in_array($array3,$array) // true
```

Any idea?

Comment: Thanks guys. Took @alexn's answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[array_intersect](http://php.net/array_intersect) will do:

```
<?php
$first = array('foo', 'bar');
$second = array('foo', 'bar','baz');

var_dump(array_intersect($first, $second) === $first); // True

$first = array('foo', 'bar', 'hello');
$second = array('foo', 'bar','baz');

var_dump(array_intersect($first, $second) === $first); // False
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`array_intersect`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-intersect.php) to intersect those two and check the number of elements in the return array:

```
$intersect = array_intersect($array1, $array2);
if (count($intersect) == count($array1)) {
   // array1 is fully contained in array2
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Or use `array_diff()`:

```
function array_contains($haystack, $needles) {
  return !count(array_diff($needles, $haystack));
}

array_contains($array2, $array1); // all elements of array1 is part of array2?
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use a for loop.

```
for ($i = 0; $i < sizeof($array1); $i++) {
  if (!in_array($array1[$i], $array2)) {
    return False;
  }
}
return True;
```